# Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex string of odd length into Go struct field SendTxArgs.data of type hexutil.Bytes

Tags: vagrant, ethereum, solidity, truffle, quorum

i have a problem that i've been trying to solve for a whole day...
I'm using Vagrant and truffle to migrate a couple of SmartContracts. The problem 
occurs right at the migration when i get an error for one of the contracts.
This is the output of the console, any help will be very much appriciated:

````
  Deploying StringUtils...
  ... 0xfff3df73a1aa886c9006dab692b3dd36fa0f0b4ab1a1f8a933b679c7d17cbadc
  StringUtils: 0x9d13c6d3afe1721beef56b55d303b09e021e27ab
  Linking StringUtils to Appalto
  Deploying Appalto...
  ... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex string of odd length into Go struct field SendTxArgs.data of type hexutil.Bytes
    at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:38:1)
    at C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:86:1
    at C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-migrate\index.js:225:1
    at C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-provider\wrapper.js:134:1
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:509:1)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\valer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:469:1)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)```
````

Comment: What's your truffle version? And can you show your migrations?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem using istanbul instead of raft within the Vagrant VM!